# Creating a 2 Column Layout in CSS

Tags: html, css, tablelayout, whmcs

I am working on the interface for a small web module and am having some problems with the CSS. Right now I have the container DIV and then tables to layout the sub-sections. I am floating 3 of the tables left and 3 tables right, which until now has worked great.

I recently added a feature that allows for additional fields to be added by the user as needed and as the height of a table in the right column grows, it breaks the layout. Is there a better way to do this so that the layout won't break?

[image]

After adding "clear:left" and "clear:right" to each table, it appears as follows...

[image]

After moving the 3 left floated tables to the top of the code and removing the "float:right/clear:right" from the other 3, it works well except for this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each float left, add clear:left, for each float right, add clear: right.

It'd depend on the order of each floated container though.  Another option would be to try keeping one set of floats from one column (i.e. the float lefts or float rights) and remove the float property from the others in the other column so they wrap to the side of the floated boxes.

EDIT: a working example: http://cssdesk.com/Xan5j

Comment: Adding clear:left/right has improved it but has some very strange behavior. It does keep the tables in their respective columns now, but after adding a certain amount of new fields, the submit button moves and the other tables line themselves up weird (i.e. "IPMI/DRAC Credentials" lining up next to "Assigned Inventory") I posted a new screenshot in the initial question. If you don't answer back, I will just accept this as answer anyways in 24 hours.

Comment: Do you have any control over the order the blocks are outputted? I can see that the order they're currently outputted is 'device' - 'network' - 'configured' - 'idmi'.. because the 'configured' block is floated right, the next float left automatically clears it.  if you can change the order, output all of your left column blocks first, floated left, then remove the float property of the right column blocks, and they will fill the space on the right...

Comment: I did as suggested, floating the 3 left tables first, then added the 3 right tables and removed the float/clear properties from them. It looked correct (except the spacing between the two columns was gone due to the float:right being removed). After adding 4+ fields though, the "RDP/SSH Credentials" jumps to the left side because the content on the right is considerably longer and nothing on the left is still there to fill it. This is considerably better in practice but creates a very strange gap after doing so (new screenshot added to first post)

Comment: okay, a better idea in that case is to output the right hand columns first, float them right. Then output left columns without float properties. This should fix the gap between them, and the wrapping issue...

Comment: It doesn't wrap the boxes around anymore to the other column but this is much better than what I started with. I appreciate your help!

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned - did you add clear: right to the right hand boxes too?

Comment: I added clear:right to the 3 columns on the right but it does not make them go to the left column like it did before. If I understand it correctly though, this is the correct behavior and just a downside to switching from the previous design to this one.

Comment: No problem, it gets confusing trying to outline it in the comments, I should have done this for you earlier, take a look at this: http://cssdesk.com/Xan5j

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to show a live example of this, but the easiest way to handle this—if this is an option—is to wrap each column in its own div.

Comment: Unfortunately it's an Admin side module and it would take quite a lot of time to extract the code and make it standalone. However, I did try doing two DIV's inside of the container div and rather than floating the tables, just place 3 in each DIV but it didn't work. I may have done something wrong though so I will give that another shot!

Comment: OK, good luck. Looking at your screen shot, I'm intrigued as to what you were doing to get the result in the first image. Are the boxes just floated?

Comment: As the code is quite long, I put it on pastie for you at http://pastie.org/7942588 I have since added the "clear:left/right" lines as suggested in the other answer but with those removed, that is how I had it initially set.